# Angular extract FormArray values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have form array like `skills = new FormArray([]);` and it contains values of multiple inputs, if I debug controls level of `skills` I will be having such data:

`console.log(this.skills.controls);`

[image: one]

What I'm looking for is to get those **values as array** and send them by my other function to back-end.

> PS: my problem is not sending data to back-end but to `get my array values as array`.

**Any idea?**

Comment: What is `this.skills.value`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `this.skills` is a [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) - so `console.log(this.skills.value)` and you'll have your array

Comment: @Adam yes it is array as i mentione `skills = new FormArray([]);` and I am testing your comment to see results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the documentation for [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray).

What you actually are looking for is the `value` property of the `FormArray`